# Developing a sample helloWorld application in Spring batch Job?

Tags: spring-batch

I had tried with some sample applications in Spring batch..
But i didn't get a clear idea about how it will work since am new to Spring framework.
Can anyone plz help me to understand the basic of this Spring batch by
a sample application.
I think in Spring batch documentation also we can't get a clear idea about developing an application ..
help plz.

Answer (score 2):

The spring batch doc should cover the basics and semantics, e.g. [Chunk-oriented Processing](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#chunkOrientedProcessing). You can also take a look at the official [Spring samples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples) on Github.

Here are some project examples on Github:

- [spring-batch-examples](https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-examples)

  - Has a Wiki page for each example
- [spring-batch-templates](https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-templates)
- [spring-batch-archetypes](https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-archetypes) (the maven archetypes for the templates above)

Comment: Is there any way to run the Batch Job without using the maven?

Comment: did you check http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/downloads.html ? there are .zip files containing all dependencies